Custom gradle Plugin to Run on Client Projects code
In our organization, we have a repository where we export a variety of plugins related to checkstyle, PMD, component testing, and Liquibase, among other things. I created a simple plugin with a task that invokes archunit rule check.
After exporting the plugin and applying it to my child project, I can see the task. However, when I run the task, the rules only check the classes within the plugin. They do not scan any classes in the child project. It seems as though the plugin operates as a self-contained unit.
How can I configure my plugin to run on the classpath of the client project?
Plugin
class ArchUnitPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
  override fun apply(project: Project) {
    val runArchUnitTests =
      project.tasks.register("runArchUnitTests", Test::class.java) {
        group = "verification"
        description = "Runs ArchUnit tests"

        val sourceSets = project.extensions.getByType<SourceSetContainer>()
        val main = sourceSets.getByName("main")

        classpath = project.files(main.runtimeClasspath)
        doLast {
          println("Task running!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
          ServiceAnnotationVerifier().verifyServiceAnnotations()
        }
      }
    runArchUnitTests.configure { dependsOn("test") }
  }
}

Rule inside plugin project
class ServiceAnnotationVerifier {
  fun verifyServiceAnnotations() {
    val importedClasses = ClassFileImporter().importPackages("..service..")

    val servicesShouldBeAnnotatedWithService =
      ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
        .that()
        .resideInAPackage("..service..")
        .and()
        .haveSimpleNameNotEndingWith("Test")
        .should()
        .beAnnotatedWith(Service::class.java)
        .orShould()
        .beAnnotatedWith(Component::class.java)
        .because("Need to ensure that all service classes are annotated with @Service")

    servicesShouldBeAnnotatedWithService.check(importedClasses)
  }
}


After applying the plugin in child project and when I run ./gradlew :runArchUnitTests I got

> Task :runArchUnitTests FAILED
Task running!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runArchUnitTests'.
> Rule 'classes that reside in a package '..service..' and have simple name not ending with 'Test' should be annotated with @Service or should be annotated with @Component, because Need to ensure that all service classes are annotated with @Service' failed to check any classes. This means either that no classes have been passed to the rule at all, or that no classes passed to the rule matched the `that()` clause. To allow rules being evaluated without checking any classes you can either use `ArchRule.allowEmptyShould(true)` on a single rule or set the configuration property `archRule.failOnEmptyShould = false` to change the behavior globally.

I am new to plugins and need suggestion on whats wrong.
Created an issue here as well
Thank you.

Do you know the ArchUnit Gradle plugin from the Société Générale?
It might already cover your use case without having to implement your own plugin.
